Inequality for minimum of two random variables
I am working with two non-decreasing functions, $T_1(t)$ and $T_2(t)$, where $t$ represents a parameter that is influenced by randomness,
$t\in[0,1]$. Specifically, I am trying to prove an inequality involving the expectations of the minimums of these two functions under slightly different conditions. Here is the inequality I am interested in:
$$
\mathbb E[\min(T_1(t), T_2(t))] \geq \mathbb E[\min(T_1(t), T_2(t'))],
$$
where $t$ and $t'$ are independent random seeds affecting $T_1$ and $T_2$, respectively. This means that in the second expectation, $T_1$ and $T_2$ are evaluated at independent instances of their input, whereas in the first expectation, they are evaluated at the same instance.
Intuitively, it should be true because in the left expectation are "correlated" and therefore minimum should be greater, than in the independent case.
I am seeking proof or any insights that could guide me toward proving this inequality.

Is there any relation between the two function $T_1(t)$ and $T_2(t)$? If there's no restriction then $T_2(t) = (\min_{t \in [0,1]} T_1(t)) - \epsilon + \epsilon t$ is a counterexample

Do you know the notion of stochastic dominance? In this kind of situation, typically what might happen is that you can put all these random variables $T_1,T_2, t, t'$ etc. in the same sample space so that $\min(T_1(t) , T_2(t)) \geq \min(T_1(t), T_2(t'))$ holds almost surely, whence the expectation inequality follows directly. This is all I can say without knowing your definitions, of course.

No, only that both functions are increasing.
$T_2(t)=T_1(t)-\epsilon+\epsilon t$ does not look like a counter-example: in the left expectation minimum is just $T_1(t)$, while in the right, it can be something smaller.

Not sure how to apply stochastic dominance and  coupling here: this inequality is satisfied only on average, not almost surely (at least in my computational experiments).

No it's $T_2(t) = (\min_{t \in [0,1]} T_1(t)) - \epsilon + \epsilon t$
not $T_1(t)-\epsilon+\epsilon t$. The consequence is that $\forall t' T_2(t') \leq T_1(t)$ so there would be an equal sign instead.

yes, sorry understood.
The inequality can be weakly greater, not ">". Functions also can be weakly increasing (i.e. non-decreasing).

w.l.o.g $\min\{E[T_2(t), E[T_2(t')] = 0$  (otherwise consider $\tilde{T_i} = T_i - \min\{E[T_2(t)], E[T_2(t')]\})$.
Then we have $E[T_2(t)] = 0$ or $E[T_2(t')] = 0$, let's assume the latter.
We have $$\min\{a,b\} = \frac{1}{2}\left(a + b - |a-b|\right)$$
and so
\begin{align*}
& E[\min(T_1(t), T_2(t))] \ge
 E[\min(T_1(t), T_2(t'))] \\
\iff & E[T_1(t) + T_2(t) - |T_1(t) - T_2(t)|] \ge E[T_1(t) + T_2(t') - |T_1(t) - T_2(t')|] \\
\iff&E[T_2(t) - T_2(t') - |T_1(t) - T_2(t)| + |T_1(t) - T_2(t')|] \ge 0
\end{align*}
And this is what we will show now.
With the reverse triangle inequality $$\left(|x| - |y|\right) \le |x+y|$$ we get
\begin{align*}
2\min\{T_2(t),T_2(t')\} &= T_2(t) + T_2(t') - |T_2(t) - T_2(t')| \quad(\text{definition }\min) \\
&= T_2(t) + T_2(t') - |T_2(t) \color{green}{- T_1(t)} \color{red}{+ T_1(t)} - T_2(t')| \\
&\le T_2(t) + \color{blue}{T_2(t')} - \left(|T_2(t) - T_1(t)| - |T_1(t) - T_2(t')|\right) \quad(\text{reverse triangle}) \\
&=T_2(t) \color{blue}{- T_2(t')} - |T_2(t) - T_1(t)| + |T_1(t) - T_2(t')| \color{blue}{+ 2T_2(t')}
\end{align*}
Consider that in the last step we could also split up $T_2(t)$ instead of $T_2(t')$. We've choosen here the latter because we are in the case where $E[T_2(t')] = 0$ but it also works the other way around if we would have $E[T_2(t)] = 0$.
Using expectactions we get in total:
\begin{align*}
0 &\le 2\min\{E[T_2(t)],E[T_2(t')]\} \\
&\le 2E[\min\{T_2(t),T_2(t')\} \\
&\le E[T_2(t) - T_2(t') - |T_2(t) - T_1(t)| + |T_1(t) - T_2(t')|] + 2E[T_2(t')] \\
&= E[T_2(t) - T_2(t') - |T_2(t) - T_1(t)| + |T_1(t) - T_2(t')|]
\end{align*}
and we are done…
